# Drop consecutive duplicates from DataFrame with multiple columns and with string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':1,'b':1,'c':'x'},{'a':1,'b':1,'c':'x'}, {'a':2,'b':2, 'c':'x'}, {'a':1,'b':2,'c':'x'}, {'a':1,'b':1,'c':'x'}])

   a  b  c
0  1  1  x
1  1  1  x
2  2  2  x
3  1  2  x
4  1  1  x
```

I'd like to drop consecutive duplicate rows only, i.e. only row at index 1

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  x
2  2  2  x
3  1  2  x
4  1  1  x
```

I was about to do that with the following code, if column c isn't str

```
df[df[['c']].diff().ne(0).any(1)]
```

However, because column c is str, diff() doesn't work. What's the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just compare the original rows with the forward-shifted rows when `.diff()` is not working. Identical rows can be found by calling `.all(axis=1)` on the result of element-wise comparison.

Solution:

```
df[~(df.shift() == df).all(axis=1)]
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c
0  1  1  x
2  2  2  x
3  1  2  x
4  1  1  x
```

Comment: thank you! this is great. I think I can also do `df[(df.shift() != df).any(axis=1)]`